# Generating bindings with automatic file list?

Tags: makefile, automake

I'm trying to generate bindings using SWIG and an automatic input file list. But apparently it is not working (`make` simply says there's nothing to do for target 'bindings'). Manually calling make as `make whatever.i` works as intended.

I have the following Makefile.am by now:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = ptpcapture2
ptpcapture2_SOURCES = *.scm
BINDSRCS = *.i
BINDSCMS = $(BINDSRCS:.i=.scm)

.i.scm:
    $(SWIG) -chicken -addextern $<

.scm.c: bindings
    $(CSC) -t -c $<

bindings: $(BINDSCMS)
```

What did I miss or do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use suffix rules, you have to [add any new suffixes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) to the list of known suffixes via the `.SUFFIXES` special target:

```
.SUFFIXES: .i .scm
```

It's simpler to just use pattern rules instead:

```
%.scm : %.i
        $(SWIG) -chicken -addextern $<

%.c : %.scm bindings
        $(CSC) -t -c $<
```

But the real problem here is that you have to be explicit about your wildcards, like:

```
ptpcapture2_SOURCES := $(wildcard *.scm)
BINDSRCS := $(wildcard *.i)
```

Why is this?  Because the globbing is not expanded when the variable is assigned, it's only expanded when the rule is run.  That means that this line:

```
BINDSCMS = $(BINDSRCS:.i=.scm)
```

sets `BINDSCMS` to the string `*.scm` because `BINDSRCS` is not expanded, it's still just the literal string `*.i`.

Why is that bad?  Because then when make sees this:

```
bindings: *.scm
```

it tries to expand the wildcard `*.scm`... but none of those files have been created yet and so they don't exist, and this expands to no files, and so as long as the target `bindings` exists there's nothing to do to rebuild it (it has no prerequisites).